# Get numerically indexed column in Dataframe with Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas

I load a dataframe from a TSV file like this:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, sep='\t')
print frame.head(1)
```

The output is:

```
                                       2008   2009   2010   2011   2012
reason,citizen,duration,unit,geo\time
EDUC,TOTAL,TOTAL,PER,AT                2853   3233   3735   5031   6298
```

The result of getting the third row:

```
s = frame.iloc[1]
print s
```

outputs:

```
2008     6743
2009     7222
2010     5899
2011     5834
2012     5813
Name: EDUC,TOTAL,TOTAL,PER,BE, dtype: object
```

Now I want to access one of the columns:

print frame['2014']

This gives a key error.

> KeyError: '2014'

How do I access the columns with their numeric labels?

Answer (score 0):

If a column label is an integer, `frame[2014]` may be used to access the content of that column. But since this may be ambiguous (when 2014 is also an index), I would suggest

```
frame.loc[:, 2014]
```

which is unambiguous: 2014 refers to column, not row; and it's a label, not position (because indexing by position would be `.iloc`)